# Finding zeros of $f:x \rightarrow J_x(a), a \in \mathbb{C}$, with $J_x(a)$ the Bessel function of the 1st kind.

Tags: bessel-functions

I'm looking for a function (preferrably in Python) which takes a complex number $a$ as input, and outputs the zeros of the function $f:x \rightarrow J_x(a)$ where $J_x(a)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. This problem is relevant to solving a Schroedinger equation in a 1D condensed matter system (N.B. I am **not** asking to find the zeros of the bessel function $f:x \rightarrow J_n(x)$).

Does anybody know of a programming language such as Python, Wolfram language, etc. which has this built-in; and if so what is that function? It would save me the effort of implementing some sort of Newton's method-esque function myself.

Please let me know if this belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: You want all the zeros in the complex plane?  I think there are typically infinitely many.  Maple's fsolve will find solutions in a given rectangle.  Unfortunately its RootFinding package seems not to work here because Maple doesn't know the derivative of $J(x,a)$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes, it's a tough question since I can't seem to get a hold of that derivative either... There must be some numerical result I can use somewhere though. All the best.

Comment: There are derivatives [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/20/01/01/), but they may be a bit long